# Broken Swapfile?

Tags: swap, rsync

I am on ubuntu 20.04 with 4GB `/swapfile` on a machine with 19GB of RAM.  I am current setting up various rsync commands tomake backups of various directories, using a command based upon the the command below:

```
cputool --load-limit 7.5 -- nice -n -15 rsync -avxP --delete --rsync-path="rsync" --log-file=/var/log/rsync-home.log --exclude 'snap'  --exclude 'lost+found' --exclude=".*" --exclude=".*/" localhost::home /media/user/external/hd/directory
```

After many moons of testing.  It seems that the rsync commands get "stuck" in swap... (i.e. existing after I kill the commands, sometimes executing but simply hanging).. I have to use `swapoff /swapfile && swapon /swapfile` to clear the swap memeory

today, I finally installed iotop on my machine and it shows the following for `/swapfile`:
[image]

Any thoughts?